# Loop to Combine Multiple PDF Files in an Output Folder that All Begin with Same Word?

Tags: r, pdftk

I have an output folder that has a series of reports, all beginning with the last name and first initial of the subject. For example:

"DoeJ Jump.Performance.pdf"

"MartinD Jump.Performance.pdf"

"DoeJ Asymmetry.pdf"

"MartinD Asymmetry.pdf"

"DoeJ TwentyJump Report.pdf"

"MartinD TwentyJump Report.pdf"

It would be amazing to be able to create a loop that could combine all the files that correspond to the name of each individual into a single PDF. I have a feeling Staplr would be the appropriate package for this, but not sure where to start from here:

```
for (i in AthleteList){
  
  staple_pdf(
    input_directory = NULL,
    input_files = NULL,
    output_filepath = NULL,
    overwrite = TRUE
  )
  
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(qpdf)
library(pdftools)
library(here)

pdf_files <- list.files(here("pdf_xxx"), pattern="^DoeJ", full.names = TRUE)

my_path <- "pdf_xxx"

pdf_combine(input = pdf_files,
            output = my_path )
```

Comment: TarJae's solution worked for a single subject/name, but I have ~60 names with corresponding pdfs in the folder. Need some sort of solution with a loop if anything comes to mind

Comment: Try putting the names in a dataframe, then looping using the unique names and put TarJae's code inside the loop ```files = data.frame(files = ...
files$names <- word(files$files,1)
for i in unique(files$names){
<<  TarJae's code here>>
}```